# Why Coulomb's Law is only valid for point charges?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

Why Coulomb's Law is only valid for point charges? Is there any reason? Why this law is not valid for other charges rather than point charges?

Comment: Note that Coulombs Law still is a good approxiation for a sufficiently large distance from the charge distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by "Coulomb's Law"?  You can do a Gaussian shell over any particle distribution and integrate to get the charge within and then multiply by another result for another enclosed charge distribution just fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you had, say, an extended object with many point charges and wanted to know the force on a point charge, Q, you would use Couldomb's Law to add up the forces on Q due to each individual charge. In the case of a continuous distribution of charge, you do a similar thing but consider the object to be made up of an infinite number of infinitesimal charges, dq, i.e. you do an integral. So in that sense Coulomb's Law is used for finding the force of the extended object on the charge Q.

But in general you can't just take the total charge of an arbitrarily shaped extended source with an arbitrary charge distribution and use Coulomb's Law to find the force on an external point charge (an exception is a spherical distribution of charge). One issue you would face is what do you use for the distance between the external point charge and the extended source?

Comment: Upvoted, but I have a comment: Adding up of Coulomb forces requires an additional assumption, which is linearity of the electric field. This is implied by Maxwell's equations, but does not follow from Coulomb's Law alone.

Comment: @Cuspy Code: Why bring the electric field into the discussion as we are dealing with the Coulomb force. But you bring up an interesting point. Is linearity of forces also an assumption?

Comment: linearity has been demonstrated experimentally.  If it breaks down it does so on a scale we cannot probe so easily.